# Finalizar un fragment al pasar a otro fragment

Tags: fragment

Hola tengo un problema he desarrollado una pequeña aplicación de galería de sonidos en el que incluí 8 fragments dinámicos en un layout, los cuales puedo cambiar con botones desde el activity_main, el problema es que al hacer unos 3 o 4 cambios la aplicacación se queda en silencio y deja de reproducir los sonidos o es que hay que ingresar algunos códigos en cada fragment?, espero me ayuden a resolver este dilema. Aquí les dejo el código de esa parte en el activity_main:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1:
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorFragments,fragment1);
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorFragments,fragment2);
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorFragments,fragment3);
            break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorFragments,fragment4);
            break;
        case R.id.btn5:
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorFragments,fragment5);
            break;
        case R.id.btn6:
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorFragments,fragment6);
            break;
        case R.id.btn7:
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorFragments,fragment7);
            break;
        case R.id.btn8:
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorFragments,fragment8);
            break;

    }


    transaction.commit();


}
```

Comment: Cual es el código que influye en la reproducción del audio?  es encuentra en la Activity o en algún Fragment?

Comment: en cada fragment hay una galeria de sonidos SoundPool, con diferentes activity si funciona pero con fragments colapsa